# XAMPP - PDO MSSQL extensions enabled, but unable to be used

Tags: sql-server, pdo, php-extension

I am currently using XAMPP for local development. I am needing to connect to a MSSQL database, in my efforts I have:

- Downloaded **SQLSRV32** packages and extracted them to 'xampp/php/ext'
- Added `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` and `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` to my *php.ini*
- Restarted Apache.
- Ensured that my environment is accessing and loading the proper *INI* file.
- I've double checked `PHPINFO()` to see that the extensions are being enabled.
  [image]
  [image]
- When I attempt to connect to the DB with the following code:

  ```
  $DB_HOST = 'ip.address.here';
  $DB_DATABASE = 'db_name';
  $DB_USER = 'db_user';
  $DB_PASSWORD = 'db-pass';
  $DSN = 'dblib:host=' . $DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . $DB_DATABASE;

  // Create connection
  try {
      $lPDO = new PDO($DSN, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
      $lPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      if($lPDO){
          error_log('MSSQL Connection Successful...');
      }

  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Connection failed'. $e->getMessage();
  }
  ```
- I get the following error in my error log file:

  **Connection failed: could not find driver**

Having read over pretty much every previous answer and question based on this topic, I'm at a loss on what I'm doing wrong. I don't feel that the connection code is wrong, and I've verified that I have access to the DB, etc...

Comment: dblib != sqlsrv

Comment: @YourCommonSense, then is there a different extension I need to consider? Or is it as simple as adjusting the DSN?

Comment: We switched over to using an ODBC DSN string, which seems to have solved our issue. I'm not sure if closing this question would be best, or making and edit with notes?